# Scanning a list - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception

I have created a Hangman game that has one bug: if you guess the same letter twice it will break.  I have created a list of every alphabet letter and when the player guesses that letter it will be removed from the list, which displays the remaining characters available to guess. This is accomplished through the .remove method, which will break if the character has already been removed from a previous guess.

I have attempted to nest this method in a for loop that will scan the alphabet list and check the user's guess for a match in the list and remove it. If it has already been guessed, then nothing will happen.  The error i receive is an index error, presumably for the length of the guess.  My confusion comes from the fact that I can accomplish this exact same task directly below when scanning the hangman word to match the player's guess.  Please see the abridged code below:

```
# Play begins and player guesses a letter
player_word = ['_ '] * len(cpu_word)
player_word2 = ['_'] * len(cpu_word)
alphabet = ['a','b',etc.]
print 'You have 10 guesses left'

# Determines if the guess is correct
for count in range(10)[::-1]:
    guess = raw_input(str('Guess a letter: '))
    # This is the previous method that creates a bug:/
    # alphabet.remove(guess)
    for e in xrange(len(alphabet)):
        if alphabet[e] == guess:
            alphabet.remove(guess)
    for i in xrange(len(cpu_word)):
        if cpu_word[i] == guess:
            player_word [i] = cpu_word [i]
            print 'Correct!'
```

I have two questions.  The first is can someone please explain this error to me, specifically why it works for scanning the hangman word but does not work for scanning the list.

And secondly, can anyone provide a solution for this problem.

I am new to coding so any info is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that after you remove an item from the array, it now has one less item, meaning that you can't go to the former end of the array. If your array of letters is 26 long, and you remove one letter, you can't access the 26th element anymore, because the array now only has 25 elements. After you guess correctly, you could just break, like so:

```
for e in xrange(len(alphabet)):
    #print alphabet[e], e
    if alphabet[e] == guess:
        alphabet.remove(guess)
        break
```

However you could just uncomment the line above, and check if it is in the array before removing it, like this:

```
for count in range(10)[::-1]:
guess = raw_input(str('Guess a letter: '))
if(guess in alphabet):
    """"This is the previous method that creates a bug:/"""
    alphabet.remove(guess)
    for i in xrange(len(cpu_word)):
        if cpu_word[i] == guess:
            player_word [i] = cpu_word [i]
            print 'Correct!'
```

Comment: I'm not sure which is the Best Practices method but both work, and I appreciate you helping me to understand why the former method did not.  Thanks!

Comment: Personally I would just use the second way (using the if statement), its less lines of code and just looks cleaner, but both work. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to loop over the alphabet, you could check if the letter is still in the alphabet with:

```
if guess in alphabet:
    #And do the function here:
    alphabet.remove(guess)
```

Your for-loop contains a flaw. You are removing the guessed letter for the alphabet, but then your for-loop continues. This causes an error because your alphabet is now one letter shorter, while the loop still thinks it is the same size as before. Therefore, break the for-loop:

```
for e in xrange(len(alphabet)):
    if alphabet[e] == guess:
        alphabet.remove(guess)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is using indexes to loop through the list, and changing the size of the list at the same time. You can either loop through the items directly:

```
for letter in alphabet:
    if letter == guess:
        alphabet.remove(guess)
```

Or you can break when you've removed the letter:

```
for e in range(len(alphabet)):
    if alphabet[e] == guess:
        alphabet.remove(guess)
        break
```

Break stops termination of the loop, which is fine because you're finished after you've removed the letter.

I think a `set` would be better than list because it offers `O(1)` removal and contains. So:

```
alphabet = ['a','b','c'...] # list, bad
alphabet = {'a','b','c'...} # set, good
```

Then your alphabet "loop" would be:

```
if guess in alphabet:
    alphabet.remove(guess)
```